# Different focus on different parts of the picture

Tags: autofocus, image-quality, sharpness

I have a problem with the camera on my Xiaomi Mi A2. It mainly occurs when I take pictures of things far away. This problem is consistent. I have added a few pictures. You can see in one of the pictures that an object close to the phone on the left side is sharp.

Does anyone have any idea, what's happening?
Thank you in advance for all help.

[image]

[image]

[image: Here is the picture with the sharp object close to the phone.]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lens is tilted and/or shifted.

Sometimes, these kinds of effects are desirable, such as [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt%E2%80%93shift_photography#/media/File:Hong_Kong_Peak_Tilt_Shift_Lens.jpg) which is called [tilt-shift photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt%E2%80%93shift_photography).

Since this is a very cheap phone and not an interchangeable lens camera, repairing it would likely cost more than the value of the phone.

Solution: get a new camera, either phone if that's what floats your boat or a better camera.

Comment: I have a dual camera on it, so I found a way to manually switch to the other one. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That doesn't look like tilt - there's *nothing* in the left of the frame that is in focus at any distance.

Comment: @MichaelC Yes, it is. Look at the shroud (the wire) in picture number three.

Comment: And also, if the lens was tilted in such a manner that focus is greater than infinity in the left side, the past-infinity focus would still be called "tilt". Basically, tilt IS lens misalignment, even if nothing is in focus at the left side.

Comment: It is far past what any movement of an actual view camera or tilt-shift lens would allow. The lens is out of alignment. It could be caused by a decentering issue just as well as a tilt issue, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a poorly made or assembled lens that has become extremely misaligned. Did you first notice the issue shortly after you might have dropped the phone and it took a serious shock impact?

It doesn't look so much like a moderate tilt issue, such as would be within the range of a view camera with movements or a tilt-shift lens, as pretty much *nothing* in the left portion of the frame is in focus, neither nearer nor further than what is in focus on the right side of the photos (other than a very near rope in the third photo in which the focus distance for the right side of the frame is very far away).

Comment: Yes, it is. Look at the shroud (the wire) in picture number three.

Comment: It is far past what any movement of an actual view camera or tilt-shift lens would allow. The lens is fairly severely out of alignment.